# Your authentication details have not been recognized or Alfresco may not be available at this time

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

Your authentication details have not been recognized or Alfresco may not be available at this time. Any idea what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: can you please share alfresco logs?

Comment: If you're confident in credentials being ok, Alfresco/Share are not working, there must be something in your logs.

Comment: https://community.alfresco.com/thread/237486-when-i-login-the-am-facing-this-error-your-authentication-details-have-not-been-recognized-or-alfresco-may-not-be-available-at-this-time-if-it-is-possible-to-delete-the-super-admin-credentials

Comment: Attached log file in the above link. Pls check

Comment: Did you change your config? Log tells tomcat is listening on http-apr-8090 but your screenshot is connecting to 8080. Log from 06-18 tells port 8090 is already occupied ...

Comment: @Heiko Robert "8080" is Development environment "8090" is live Environment

Comment: @vikash  pls check the above link to log files

Comment: are you using any customization?

Comment: @vikash No i did'nt